# codeigniter change content without refresh page by clicking anchor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to change only my webpage content without refreshing the page,

**view**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('site2/getBranchDetails/'.$row_bank->branch_id.''); ?>"><?php echo $row_bank->bank;  ?></a>
```

this link is on my nav bar,when I click this link I need to change content, there need to pass id to my controller,

**controller**

```
 public function getBranchDetails($b_id){
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->bank_account_model->getAccount($b_id);
    }
```

and data in the result array should be view in the view content,I need ajax soution

Comment: Show us the ajax code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="branch" alt="123">CLick me</a>
```

the PHP

```
public function getBranchDetails(){

    $b_id = $this->input->post('branch_id');
    $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
    $data = $this->bank_account_model->getAccount($b_id); //suppose its ->result();

    $rows  ='<ul>'; //i use ul, use table if u want
    foreach($data as $r){

        $rows .='<li>'.$r->branch_city.'</li>';
        $rows .='<li>'.$r->branch_name.'</li>';
    }
    $rows .='</ul>';


   echo json_encode(array('data'=>$rows));
}
```

here's the jquery/ajax

```
$(function(){

 $(".branch").click(function(){

    var branch_id = $(this).attr("alt");

    $.ajax({

     url : 'your_url/getBranchDetails',type:'post',dataType:'json',
     data: {branch_id:branch_id},
     success:function(result){

        //fetch result.data
         alert(result.data); //do it yourself from here 
         //(append it somewhere)
         $('body').append(result.data);
      }

     })
  })
})
```

Comment: in here what is the id

Comment: it returns [object Object]

how can I view data

Comment: alt="123"  on your anchor is the ID, take a look again, i've updated ..please set it as the answer if you found this correct

Comment: here I need to display results in my view,not in controller,do u know mvc architecture

Comment: Well...yes sir I understand

i believe that was the solution. 
I'm sorry it just doesnt meet you need

Comment: use console.log to see the result. [object object] means you got the result. You just need to process it now.